# MediaPlayer is not pausing the audio file

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have an audio recording application which will record audio through a mic, after recording audio it will play the audio when the user press play button, till here it works great, but I want to pause the audio file while playing when the user clicks the pause button. This is my java code.  How to do that?

```
public class tab1 extends Fragment {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private Button play,stop,record;
private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder;
private String outputfile;


public tab1() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1,container,false);


    final ImageButton  record=(ImageButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.record);
   final ImageButton stop=(ImageButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.stop);
   final ImageButton play=(ImageButton) rootview.findViewById(R.id.play);
    final  ImageButton pause=(ImageButton)rootview.findViewById(R.id.pause);


 stop.setVisibility(getView().INVISIBLE);


    File directorysample=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+separator+"RadioRecords");
    directorysample.mkdirs();
    String filename = "/recording_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp3";
    final  String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/RadioRecords";
    outputfile = directory + "/" + filename;




    record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            try {


                myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
                myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputfile);
                myAudioRecorder.prepare();
                myAudioRecorder.start();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException ise){



            }catch (IOException ioe){



            }
         // record.setEnabled(false);
          //stop.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setVisibility(getView().VISIBLE);


        }

    });


    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            myAudioRecorder.stop();
        //   record.setEnabled(true);
            myAudioRecorder.release();
            myAudioRecorder=null;
         //stop.setEnabled(false);
       //play.setEnabled(true);


            stop.setVisibility(getView().INVISIBLE);

        }

    });
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputfile);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
    });

    pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputfile);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.pause();


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }

        }
    });
    return rootview;
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use multiple MediaPlayers for play and pause. Use One MediaPlayer. Initiate it in onCreateView or play onClick and use where you want.

Declare one MediaPlayer globally:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

Initiate it in onCreateView or play onClick:

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

And replace this:

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputfile);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.pause();
```

With:

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
     mediaPlayer.pause();
}
```

Comment: But it can record, stop, play not pause, why?

Comment: Look carefully. You used same MediaRecoder for  play and stop. Thats why it worked. But you initiated two new MediaPlayers for PLAY and PAUSE. When you press PLAY, new MediaPlayer is created and started playing. In this situation when you press press PAUSE, you are creating another new MediaPlayer and the previous one is gone. So the previous one keeps playing and "Pause MediaPlayer" has nothing to stop. Hope this clears things up. Sorry for lengthy comment

Comment: Did you remove MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer(); in pause.setonClickListener ?

Comment: :( You can add your latest code if you like so that I can take a look.

Comment: hehe its working dude, i marked your qustion, if u can upvote my qustion, thanks